# Multiple groupby error: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df. As you can see there may be multiple prices per token from the same day. So I want to take the median day price.

```
    token_address                                date       close
0   0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48  2021-08-18  1.078874e-07
1   0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48  2021-08-18  1.088589e-07
2   0xa80f2c8f61c56546001f5fc2eb8d6e4e72c45d4c  2021-08-18  2.835567e-07
3   0xbbc2ae13b23d715c30720f079fcd9b4a74093505  2021-08-18  1.633322e-06
4   0xd2877702675e6ceb975b4a1dff9fb7baf4c91ea9  2021-08-18  3.201045e-06
...
```

So I did the following

```
prices_DEX['median'] = prices_DEX.groupby(['token_address', 'date'])['close'].median()
```

and I get an error msg:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

So I do the following:

```
prices_DEX['median'] = prices_DEX.groupby(['token_address', 'date'], as_index = False)['close'].median().reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
```

and a different error msg

```
KeyError: 'median'
...
ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (1057570, 3)
```

help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you compare len of `prices_DEX` and `prices_DEX.groupby(['token_address', 'date'])['close'].median()` you'll find out that they are not the same so you cannot just create a new column based on `groupby` results.

You can try to do it like this:

```
temp_df = prices_DEX.groupby(['token_address', 'date'])['close'].median()
prices_DEX['median'] = prices_DEX.apply(lambda x: temp_df[x.token_address][x.date], axis = 1)
```